# How can I input a vector?

Tags: support, mathjax

I input \vec x but it doesn't change a vector x.

What is the wrong?

In addition to it, I couldn't input \ldot.

[Edit, JL] Really? $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ Works for me!

Oh, I did not know that I should use $ for every format.
Thanks a lot .

$\vec{x}$

Comment: I added the TeX-code to your post. Take a look! What is `\ldot` supposed to do? I have used `\cdot`, as in $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$, and `\ldots`, when I type set a list like $1,2,\ldots,n$. But what is `\ldot`? $\ldot$ is an unrecognized command and is displayed in red to indicate an error.

Comment: Even in $\rm\LaTeX$ you need to use dollar signs (or `\(\)` and `\[\]`, which I think you can also use here.)

Answer (score 3):

Inline latex code needs to be enclosed in dollar signs: `$\vec x$` gives $\vec x$. Out of line formulas can be enclosed in double dollar signs: `$$\vec x$$` gives $$\vec x$$